# python type alias, pydantic constranined list, and mypy

Tags: python, pydantic

Related to https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/975.

I basically have:

```
Class A(BaseModel):
    x: int

Class B(BaseModel):
    as:  # List of A, size >=1

Class C(BaseModel):
    as:  # List of A, size >=1 (same as above)
```

**GOAL**

1. Enforce the constraint size >=1.
2. Not have to repeat myself in the definitions of B and C. So hopefully use a type alias for that list of As that I can then use as the type of B and C.
3. Pass mypy.

This works for the constraint and not repeating myself:

```
ListA = conlist(A, min_items=1)
```

However, the following doesn't typecheck with mypy:

```
as: ListA
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a solution that achieves all three of these goals?

Comment: Ah, that seems to work! I must have been doing something wrong before, thank you!

Comment: Not sure what to edit, do you mean removing this part `as: List[A] = Field(..., min_items=1)`, is that the invalid part?